# glfw code not running and skipping after compiling without errors

Tags: c, glfw

I am trying to learn the `glfw` library in C. I have installed the `glfw` pre-compiled binaries from their official website. I have moved the 32-bit libs from the pre-compiled binaries zip file to my `mingw-gcc`'s lib folder and the include files from the zip file to the `mingw-gcc`'s `include` folder. I am trying to make the a window using the library and c. I am using vscode as my editor. This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello World!\n"); //test line
  GLFWwindow * window;
  if (!glfwInit) {
    printf("glfw3 initialization failed");
    return -1;
  } else {
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
      printf("Could not create window.");
      glfwTerminate();
      return -1;
    } else {
      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
      while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
      }
      glfwDestroyWindow(window);
      glfwTerminate();
      return 0;

    }

  }
}
```

I am using the following command to compile my code:

```
gcc main.c -lglfw3dll -lopengl32
```

The program compiles without any errors but when I run the compiled `.exe`, nothing happens. I even tried to print hello world before the code runs, but even that doesn't print. What is happening and how do I fix it?

Edit: I fixed the problem by adding the glfw libraries to my system path. now it is working fine

Comment: Does "Hello World!" print if you flush `stdout` directly after printing it?

Comment: Do you also run it from a terminal? If not, you might to get some user input to get the terminal window to stay open (if it exits quickly you might not see anything).

Comment: Yeah I run the code from the terminal

Comment: @Yun no it does not print after flushing stdout

Comment: Please make your edit a real answer and mark it (later), this is perfectly fine. It will help others looking for the same issue to quickly find it.

Comment: It appears that glad is not loaded at all (`gladLoadGLLoader` not called)? Perhaps this causes UB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the glfw libraries to my system path. now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
if (!glfwInit)
```

This just checks to see if the *address* of `glfwInit` is non-zero.

It does *not* call/invoke it.

To *invoke* it, you want:

```
if (! glfwInit())
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> the code still is doing nothing. it is still not printing the test hello world –
> The Parallax

The `"Hello World"` in your `glfwCreateWindow` call *just* sets the window title.

The first question is: Does a window come up on the screen? That is, what, exactly, do you mean by *the code is doing nothing ...*?

I don't see any drawing calls in your code.

Your code is *similar* to the example code from: https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html#example-code with some small exceptions but not exactly the same.

In the link, it has:

```
/* Render here */
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

at the top of the loop.

AFAICT, this will clear the buffer to the background color.

You may need/want to add some drawing calls to put up a rectangle (e.g.) *after* the `glClear` call.

Otherwise, you may get the window to come up, but it won't have anything in it.

Here is the step by step tutorial: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/quick.html

It has a more complete/extensive example code. I'd use the code in the two links as a model.

Comment: the code still is doing nothing. it is still not printing the test hello world